# Carbon creating data wrong

Tags: laravel

I want to create a carbon date, but I got some error, and I don't know what...

```
    $data = '20-02-2018 00-00-00';
    $data_carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h-m-s', $data);

    dd($data_carbon);
```

Results:

```
Carbon {#321 ▼
  +"date": "2017-12-20 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo"
}
```

The date is wrong... Has to be in that format with the 00:00:00, because just below, I will execute a query showing the link of the day.

Query:

```
return Link::with('page', 'tag')
->orderBy('clicks', 'desc')
->where('sponsored', 0)
->where('status', 1)
->whereDate('created_at', $data_carbon)
->first();
```

Comment: You're passing `h-m-s `  on your from format, and `m` stands for months, shouldn't it be an `i` ? edit, just check @Alexey Mezenin answer, not detailing exactly what you're doing wrong but it has the working solution

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
$data_carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H-i-s', $data);
```

Or use `parse()`:

```
$data_carbon = Carbon::parse($data);
```

Then use the object:

```
->whereDate('created_at', $data_carbon)
```

You can also use the `format()` method to convert the datetime to any format:

```
->whereDate('created_at', $data_carbon->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
```